# Did any Ents fight for Sauron in the War of the Last Alliance?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

In the Silmarillion it is said about the Battle of Dagorlad:

> All living things were divided that day, and some of every kind, even
>   of beasts and birds, were found in either host, save the Elves only.

That implies that even some Ents fought for Sauron, and some orcs fought for the Last Alliance. Is that true, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

You're reading too far into it. The Ents were spirits of good and wouldn't have fought for Sauron, similarly Orcs have spirits of evil and wouldn't have fought for the Last Alliance.

Let's nitpick the quote.

> All living things were divided that day, and some of every kind

Tolkien seems to be using what's commonly called "*A figure of speech*". Every living thing **may** have been divided, but whether or not every living thing was at the battle is questionable. They may have been divided but not present.

> even of beasts and birds

Ents seem to exempt from this being neither beast nor birds.

> were found in either host, save the Elves only.

This seems to be suggesting they were fighting on either side, but again I think Tolkien is using an exaggeration to increase the "impressiveness" of the battle.

Comment: Although then again Treebeard was originally in league with the Enemy and even held Gandalf captive. Though at this point he wasn't an Ent but a Stone Giant. But I agree with you. Orcs fighting for the Last Alliance? I don't think so. And Ents fighting for Sauron? I think the OP is reading too much into it as well.

Comment: Treebeard was a stone giant?

Comment: Nope. [Treebeard](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Treebeard) was always an Ent, created at the same time all other Ents were, before the creation of the stars.

Comment: As for the question / this answer, Ents and Eagles were both created at the behest of Yavanna to defend trees and animals respectively from _all_ the races of Middle-Earth. Given that the forces of evil are only capable of mocking or destroying life, not creating it, I find it highly unlikely that any Ent or Eagle would have fought for them. At best, they would have stayed out of it, as they did in response to Saruman until they discovered how he had butchered the forest to fuel his industry.

Comment: @TGnat Treebeard as a stone giant was little more than a footnote or an entry in a draft outline of LotR, much in the same way Aragorn was originally a Hobbit named Trotter.

Comment: I don't like this answer enough to accept it. "All living things"/"Some of every kind save the Elves only" clearly includes Ents and Orcs. Elves are also neither beasts nor birds. I know it seems _unlikely_ for Ents to fight for Sauron, hence I asked the question.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Please see chepner's response to TGnat.

Answer (score 3):

The question is more interesting than it appears to be at first glance.

One perhaps significant implication of the passage cited by the o/p is the implication that the *Entwives* fought in the War of the Last Alliance, with the additional implication that they fought *against* Sauron.

We know from what Treebeard recounted to Merry and Pippin that the Entwives made their gardens to the East of the Great River, and that war swept over them. Treebeard specifically says that the gardens of the Entwives were laid waste by this war, and that Men now call them *the Brown Lands*.

Is it too much of a stretch to say that the Entwives may have resisted the destruction of their beloved gardens?

Treebeard himself gives some credence to this, suggesting that the war *swept away* the Entwives, for he clearly believed they had survived it, since a long Age of the world later the Ents were still searching for them.

To their sorrow, they never found them. The reader is left with the impression that they likely perished in that war, hence it seems possible they may have been participants in it.

On the other side, fighting *for* Sauron, were the Trolls, whom Sauron had made in mockery of Ents. Thus we have, on Gil-Galad's side, the Entwives, and on Sauron's side the Trolls.

Sadly, the Trolls survived. We know this, as today some abide on the Internet!   :-)

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes, it's possible.

I'll point out that the Ents aren't a race that is entirely good. Take, for instance, [Old Man Willow](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Old_Man_Willow) who may have been a Huorn rather than a proper Ent, but the two are closely related, and who is blatantly murderous towards anyone who sets foot in his woods! It's possible that similarly corrupted Ents may have fought for Sauron.

Additionally, Trolls were "made in mockery of Ents", as Orcs were made from Elves, according to Treebeard. It might be possible that some of the original stock of corrupted Ents decided to side with Sauron along with their Troll kinfolk, if any of them had survived that long.

Comment: Old Man Willow is not an Ent, as your link says.

Comment: @OrangeDog Ents and Huorns are both closely related, so if one could turn evil, I don't see why the other couldn't.