# What (if anything) do we know about the orcs who fought against Sauron?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, the-silmarillion

So, in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253555/what-did-the-dwarves-do-during-the-first-reign-of-sauron-and-why-werent-they-a), I saw that it was mentioned that all the races of Middle-earth, save the Elves, fought both for and against Sauron during the War of the Last Alliance.

*The Silmarillion* states:

> All living things were divided in that day, and some of every kind, even of beasts and birds, were found in either host, save the Elves only. They alone were undivided and followed Gil-galad. Of the Dwarves few fought upon either side; but the kindred of Durin of Moria fought against Sauron.

Presumably, the race of Orcs would have been included within that category of "all living things". What, if anything, do we know about the Orcs who fought against Sauron? Do we know anything about what happened to them afterwards? Could they have been the ancestors of the unaffiliated goblins who appeared in The Hobbit?

Comment: This is fabulous. I wonder if Tolkien himself was aware that Orcs, Trolls, Dragons, (Mewlips?), etc. fit in that category?

Comment: Presumably there were evil eagles too, surprisingly.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez The passage explicitly mentions "birds", they're spiritual messengers and servants of the king of the Valar, and they're noted as being proud, so maybe Sauron used their pride to corrupt some of them?

Comment: @nick012000 well Saruman had birds working for him too

Comment: Non-canon, but in Shadow of Mordor (and its DLC set in the Second Age) various orcs are persuaded and/or dominated in order to fight against Sauron.

Comment: Well obviously this can't be read literally. I doubt there were good balrogs, spawns of Ungoliant and Sackville-Baggins fighting there.

Comment: @Amarth I think that giant spiders might count as "beasts", Balrogs are a subcategory of Maiar (who were on both sides, as the Wizards and Sauron are both members of that race), and Hobbits didn't exist yet (and were descended from a subrace of Men, anyway, IIRC).

Comment: @nick012000 Similarly, which maiar would be on the good guys side? This is before the Istari arrived.

Comment: @Amarth *double checks the timeline* Oh, right. It's also possible that the Maiar don't count as "living things", because they're spiritual beings that predate the creation of Arda.

Comment: @nick012000 Of course they are living things. One of them (Melian) even got a child with an elf. Hobbits existed. As did ents, can you picture ents fighting for Sauron?

Comment: @Amarth "As did ents, can you picture ents fighting for Sauron?" Yes. See the answer I wrote on the question here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163943/did-any-ents-fight-for-sauron-in-the-war-of-the-last-alliance?rq=1

Comment: I always took this as either non-literal or with a very broad definition of "every kind". It's not just Orcs, Dragons and Trolls seem to be all evil too...  But they are corrupted from pre-existing living things (probably*) so might be considered to fall under the same "kind" as their originals - if Hobbits are Men, maybe Orcs are Elves (or also Men, or beasts... Tolkien changed his ideas on Orc origins a *lot*). "Every kind" might be as simple as "Spirits/Ainur, Elves, Men, Dwarves, Beasts, Birds" (and maybe 'intelligent plants' eg Old Man Willow and Ents).

Comment: *Stone-trolls may be "counterfeits" rather than corruptions, thus turning back to the stone they ultimately are in sunlight... but in that case they are arguably not "living things" anyway.

Comment: @Amarth unclear. Tolkien later suggested the Blue Wizards might have arrived in the Second Age, so they could have been around (...but probably wouldn't have been allowed to fight in the climactic battle personally, anyway). Ents and Eagles are apparently spirits of some sort sent from beyond Ea by Eru in response to Yavanna, though ("Of Aule and Yavanna" in the Silmarillion) - maybe they qualify.

Comment: Did Orcs even exist back then? I thought they were artifically created, as some kind of evil perversion of elves, which means there must have been some point in ME history where they didn't exist yet (and Elves did). If at that point Sauron still had *actual* elves fighting for him, it seems like he wouldn't (yet) have needed to create his own.

Comment: @T.E.D. Orcs definitely existed at this time - their origin was repeatedly revised by Tolkien, but even the latest possible origin was when Morgoth returned to Middle-Earth before the rising of the Sun (so two Ages before this battle). The published Silmarillion has them being created from Elves (as you say) in Utumno, before the Elves ever went to Valinor (vastly earlier). Tolkien's later notes suggest an origin from Men - likely corrupted by Sauron while Melkor was captive - but this requires an early Awakening of Men that never made it into the stories.

Comment: (Tolkien's original, pre-LOTR idea of Orc origins was that they were literally made by Melkor. The Elf idea came in when he decided that Melkor couldn't create life/souls. Other ideas included Orcs as beasts given intelligence and speech - but not true rational souls - by Melkor; some Orc-captains/Great Orcs as weak Maiar; and the the possibility of multiple 'strains' - "it remains terribly possible that there was an Elvish strain in the Orcs" - not clearly explained, but I guess meaning Orcs could be some hybrid of these different origins.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no reference anywhere to Orcs fighting against Sauron in this battle, or any actual battle - but it *is* stated in one of the Myths Transformed essays (*The History of Middle-earth* vol. X: "Morgoth's Ring") that

> Morgoth not Sauron is the source of Orc-wills. Sauron is just another (if greater) agent. Orcs can rebel against him without losing their own irremediable allegiance to evil (Morgoth).

However, this essay is one of many contradictory conceptions of the origin and nature of Orcs - and one that apparently was not "final" or ultimately accepted - and thus can't be treated as canon.

But at least at one point Tolkien considered it possible for Orcs to "rebel" against Sauron in some sense - but whether that just means escaping from his control (as Gorbag and Shagrat discuss the possibility of in *The Lord of the Rings*) or actually fighting against Sauron isn't clear.

"Every kind" is not clearly defined so may not need to be taken as a clear statement that Orcs did fight on the side of good in this battle. "Kinds" might be as broad as "Ainur/Spirits*, Elves, Men, Dwarves, Beasts, Birds".

*Sauron was a Maia, and the Ents and Eagles are apparently spirits of some sort per "Of Aulë and Yavanna" in *The Silmarillion*.

Comment: Orc battled Orc frequently for relatively trivial reasons, as when they fought one another over Frodo's gear in Minas Morgul. If one tribe of Orc battled another, let's say in the Misty Mountains, and only one of these tribes were allied with Sauron, that could count as fighting against Sauron without aiding Men or Elves directly.

Comment: Gil-Galad is associated with the War of the Last Alliance, so the quotation is presumably a reference to that event, in the Second Age. It's interesting that Elves were originally dwellers in the twilight, who dwelt in the starlight of the Elder Days, whilst Orcs were creatures of the Great Darkness, also in the Elder Days. Orcs were afraid of light, Elves were not: Morgoth created the Great Darkness to combat the new lights of the Elves, the Sun and Moon. And Elves and Orcs do seem to be two sides of the same coin, for they were the main protagonists of Morgoth's war, and on opposite sides.

Comment: @Invisible Trihedron: Yes, fighting in the Misty Mountains seems very plausible (though I think in the context of the essay the reference may be to Gorbag/Shagrat's discussion about escape). But a battlefield with Sauron directly involved (as in the Last Alliance) seems much less likely - I doubt Orcs could oppose his will in that situation. The direct presence of Sauron was very daunting to all but the greatest, and Sauron had some kind of 'telepathic' control over Orcs given their helplessness at his final fall/the Ring's destruction.

Comment: @Ed999: The "Great Darkness" is I think somewhat ambiguous (and more so because Tolkien planned to revise the Silmarillion mythology to have the Sun and Moon pre-date the Trees, with the Darkness being Morgoth's volcanic smoke - but never put this into the actual stories, just notes for revision). But in the context of LOTR, which was written before that, it seems to mean the era when Melkor/Morgoth was present in Middle-Earth, and especially before the Sun was created (at the time of Utumno, and again between his return to Middle-Earth and the first Sunrise e.g. the First and Second Battles).

Comment: @cometaryorbit:  I appreciate the information, because I've never fully understood all the twists and turns which the conflicting accounts of the Elder Days contain! I'm not sure that we can base very much on scattered notes about possible revisions that were never written. All I meant is that the Orcs were created - apparently - during the Great Darkness. Which was why they feared daylight. As a creature intended as an opposite to Elves, it is slightly odd that the Elves flourished in the twilight, _when the darkness was fearless_.

Comment: I think "opposite" is not quite what is meant by "in mockery of" the Elves - Melkor warped and corrupted the Children of Iluvatar as sort of an 'insult' to Iluvatar, not just to create soldiers. While hostile to the Elves they are not really opposites.